# Sql Query Grouping and Limiting

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization, limit

I have following sql query it is gruping according to topicName column (also it makes some division operation). 
 I want to get 2 row for each grouped topic not all.

```
    SELECT wwt.topicName, t.topic_cnt as sumOfWordsInTopic,
               wwt.word, wwt.wordCount,
               (wwt.wordCount / t.topic_cnt) AS wordProbability
         FROM weightallofwordsintopic  as wwt JOIN
             (SELECT  topicName, sum(wordCount) AS topic_cnt
              FROM weightallofwordsintopic 
              GROUP BY topicName
            ) t 
         ON wwt.topicName = t.topicName
```

weightallofwordsintopic table is as ;

```
topicName | word | wordCount
---
topic0  | word1     | 10  
topic0  | word2     | 20  
topic0  | word3     | 30  
topic0  | word4     | 40  
topic0  | word5     | 50  
topic0  | word6     | 60 

topic1  | word7     | 10  
topic1  | word8     | 20  
topic1  | word9     | 30  
topic1  | word10    | 40  
topic1  | word11    | 50  
topic1  | word12    | 60 

topic2  | word13    | 10  
topic2  | word14    | 20  
topic2  | word15    | 30  
topic2  | word16    | 40  
topic2  | word17    | 50 
topic2  | word18    | 60
```

I want output to be (ordering according to their weight but here I just put a sample (select queries above returns some differents columns))
I want to limit above query to 2 row for each grouped topicName according to their weight in column.

```
topicName | word | wordCount

topic0  | 1     | 60  
topic0  | 1     | 50  

topic1  | 1     | 60 
topic1  | 1     | 50  

topic2  | 1     | 60 
topic2  | 2     | 50
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, probably the simplest method is to use variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT wwt.topicName, t.topic_cnt as sumOfWordsInTopic, wwt.word, wwt.wordCount,
              (wwt.wordCount / t.topic_cnt) AS wordProbability,
              (@rn := if(@t = wwt.topicName, @rn + 1,
                         if(@t := wwt.topicName, 1, 1)
                        )
              ) as rn
      FROM weightallofwordsintopic  as wwt JOIN
           (SELECT topicName, sum(wordCount) AS topic_cnt
            FROM weightallofwordsintopic 
            GROUP BY topicName
           ) t 
           ON wwt.topicName = t.topicName CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @t := '', @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY wwt.topicName, wwt.wordCount DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new myself, but I believe if you use TOP, in your SELECT statement that would do the trick. Something like:
'SELECT TOP 2 wwt.topicName, etc..